# Sort eigenvalue matrix with eigenvector matrix

Tags: sorting, wolfram-mathematica, eigenvector, eigenvalue

I have N eigenvalues in column vector form.
Thus there are N eigenvectors corresponding to these eigenvalues, forming an eigenvector matrix.

Now, the problem I am working on requires me to sort the eigenvalues column vector in descending order. How do I sort the eigenvectors matrix in the same order as their eigenvalues in order to preserve correspondence?

Comment: Note that when machine numbers are used in Mathematica, `Eigensystem` already returns the eigenvalues/vectors sorted in descending order.

Comment: Eigensystem will return eigenvalues and eigenvectors with the latter in order that corresponds to the former. Daniel Lichtblau

Comment: I do want to point out one thing, for degenerate eigenvectors (i.e. same eigenvalue) of a numerical matrix, `Eigenvectors` and `Eigensystem` return vectors that are linearly independent, not orthogonal. This bit me more than once. But, you can use `Orthogonalize` on the degenerate set to give you an orthogonal set.

Comment: @rcollyer, just checked and you are right!  I didn't know this ...

Comment: @rcollyer, I believe you don't need to separate the degenerate set before orthogonalizing, a simple `Orthogonolize@Eigenvalues[m]` should do it.  At least for as long as it uses Gram-Schmidt.  Can someone confirm?

Comment: @Szabolcs, yeah, nothing like relying on their orthogonality when they're not. And, you're right, you can use `Orthogonalize` on the whole set directly as it won't affect the orthogonality of the different subspaces.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For example,

```
m = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {5, 5}];
{evals, evecs} = Eigensystem[m];
SortBy[Transpose[{evals, evecs}], First]
```

or if you want them in the same form, replace the last line by

```
Transpose@SortBy[Transpose[{evals, evecs}], First]
```

EDIT: while I used `{evals,evecs}=Eigensystem[m]`, that's not necessary. I could just have used `s=Eigensystem[m]` and then used `s` wherever I currently have `{evals,evecs}`.

Comment: oh, you beat me to it ;) i'll delete my answer

Comment: You, sir, are a scholar and a champ.

Answer (score 9):

While @acl and @yoda's ways of sorting (i.e. pairing the list elements then sorting together) is easy and commonly used, I'd like to show another generic method to easily sort an arbitrary number of lists based on one particular list (`list1`):

```
oo = Ordering[list1]; (* this finds the sorting order of list1 *)
list1[[oo]]
list2[[oo]]
list3[[oo]]  (* these order some other lists in the same way *)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Sort` function to sort the eigensystem according to the eigenvalues.

```
mat = (#*Transpose@#) &@RandomReal[NormalDistribution[], {4, 4}];
eigsys = Sort@Transpose@Eigensystem[mat];
```

`Sort`'s default behavior is to sort by the first column.

Comment: I'm not sure; it's something I observed and after playing with a few test cases, I was satisfied and I've always used it for sorting by first column...  I tend to do that till something goes horribly wrong which is when I go read the docs :)

Comment: I was under the impression that in sorting lists, it implements a lexical sort, i.e. `{1,0,3}` is before `{1,0,4}`. So, on a cursory examination, it would appear to be sorting by the first column, it is actually sorting by them all.

Comment: @rcollyer, it indeed does a lexicographic sort

Answer (score 0):

> Using Mathematica:

```
matrix = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {4, 4}];
{evals, evecs} = Chop[Transpose[Sort[Transpose[Eigensystem[matrix]]]]];
```

> OutPut:

```
evals
{-0.296769, 0.187003, 0.52714, 2.00376}

evecs 
{{-0.412673,0.844056,-0.0718614,-0.334823}, 
{-0.370973,  -0.472126, 0.76248, 0.241042},
{-0.253163,  0.1719,  -0.786782, 0.536034},
{0.557741,  0.381364,  0.65039, 0.347102}}
```